# I would like to create a application Installler that installes on a remote server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, setup-project

I would like to create a application Installer that installs my application on a remote server.

Basically I want my Installer to install the application on a windows server and i just give it the address and credentials.

I already got the installer working on a local machine. but now i want it to install on a given server.

Comment: how do you build your installer? MSI, NSIS, visual studio setup project??

Comment: i used visual studio setup project. Right now i copy the installer on the server and runn it from ther  via remote descktop, i want to skip that step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) is your friend.

You can use it to run your installer remotely, but you will need access to the remote machine to install it in the first place.

Comment: It's a good alternative if i don't find a way to integrate remote instalation functionallity in my installer i will use it.